# Sync MSHFlexGrid loading from array

Tags: vb6, mshflexgrid

I'm trying to display a 15,000 X 30 array using MSHFlexGrid.
I don't want to load all 15,000 records, just those needed for display while the user pages or scrolls.
So I want to sync the array records to the MSHFlexGrid for proper display.
I've read through quite a few Q&As online but have not found anything that addresses this specific question.
There is plenty information out there about using datasets to sync up but nothing I could find for arrays. There must be some way to sync the Grid rows of the control to the array elements without writing custom code for keys and scroll bars?

Comment: If you want VB to handle filling the displayed portion of the grid automatically, as it would if it were a data-bound control, I think you're out of luck.  Of course, if you just populate all 15,000 rows, in theory the FlexGrid will take care of itself, but that's a lot of rows - without having actually tried it, I suspect that you might run into some performance problems.

However, writing the necessary routines in the scroll and other row change events might not be that hard - I've certainly used similar techniques without too much difficulty.  (Sorry if I've mis-understood your question.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes it works fine if I load all 15,000 rows into the control and yes there is a too big performance hit which is what I'd like to avoid. Back in the DOS days you'd have to capture keystrokes and do the page-row arithmetic which as I recall was easy to get wrong. Nowadays there are mouse and mouse wheel issues to deal with in addition.

Comment: Whenever you deal with such datasets, ask yourself: would a user _really_ browse through all of this data? Or wouldn't it make more sense to let the user first specify some kind of filter.

Comment: The objective is to not have to load all the data but rather load a couple of pages at a time if need be. Your idea would be another way to accomplish this but users still need to be able to scroll.  I'm sure there will be some who will lean on the PgDn key. The user specifies the data he wants to load/use in a previous operation. His requirement could be 1 row or 20,000.